# Module content in multiple languages

Tags: magento2, language

I need to develop a module that manage content created by users (recipes in this case), but the store have multi languages. Since the content isn't static I can't use __() function.

I thought in these solutions to solve this problem:

**Solution 1:**
The simplest is create a column in the database and store the store id, but it is not a good solution, because I'll have multiple records on the "same" content.

**Solution 2:**
Create a table to store the key-value content of entity, so, if we have a entity called Recipe, we would have something like this in database:

```
entity_id, key, value, store_id
1, title, Helado de fresa, 3 #spanish
1, title, Strawberry ice cream, 4 #english
```

Are there any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much code on this for Magento 2 but I can give some explanations.
Indeed the solutions seem to be what you already suspect, but I'm going to give some example that you can take into account.

Option 1, that looks cleaner, but not that easy to maintain.
You need an EAV approach same as the products and categories in the core do.
Instead of having one table for your entity you will have at least 3 of them.
One main table that will hold the PK id and values that are not language dependent (status, create date, ...) and at least 2 tables that hold the store view specific values.

both will have the structure

```
recipe_id, store_id, attribute_id, value
```

the difference is that for one the `value` field is `varchar` and for the other one is `text`. You can even do it in one table and have the `value` as text but you will waste some disk space like that.
`attribute_id` is the id of the attribute you add in the `eav_attribute` table for your entity.

If you have other types of fields in your entity that depend on the store view you will have to create a table for each type (int, decimal, date, ...).
Bout the coding...good luck. You can take a look at how the categories are stored.

Option 2, one flat table with a store it field.
Or 2 tables, one with the entity and one that makes a many-to-many relation to the stores (entity_id, store_id). This way you can display one entity on multiple store views if needed.
It's not that clean because you will have to duplicate (as you say) a lot of values like status for example.
but it's easier to code. You can use the CMS pages as an example.

Comment: Your comment was very helpful. Thanks, Marius! I'll try to use the first option you mentioned.